# Sequelize findAll() try to get unregistered field

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

i have problem with sequelize, i try to use findAll() to get data from my table, but there is an error which says unknown column jobs.userId in field list which i never register in my model or in my table

i have tried to use findAndCountAll() but still have same error, i also tried to remove all associatoin at get same result, the only work solution so far is put userId on exclude array

here's my controller

```
const jobData = await jobs.findAll({
        attributes:{exclude:['updatedAt']},
        include:[{
            model:jobOwners,
            as:'owner',
            attributes:['id','profilePicture'],
            include:[{
                model:users,
                as:'user',
                attributes:['id','name'],
            },{
                model:districts,
                as:'district',
                attributes:['id','name']
            }]
        }]
    });
```

here's my jobs model

```
'use strict';
   module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const jobs = sequelize.define('jobs', {
      jobOwnerId:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false
      },
      caption: {
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false
      },
      description: {
        type:DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull:false
      },
      districtId: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false
      },
      address: {
        type:DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull:false
      },
      poster: {
        type:DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull:true
      },
      contactPerson: {
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false
      }
   }, {});
   jobs.associate = function(models) {
     jobs.belongsTo(models.jobOwners,{as:'owner',foreignKey:'jobOwnerId'})
     jobs.belongsTo(models.districts,{as:'districts', foreignKey:'districtId'})
   };
   return jobs;
 };
```

here's my table

```
CREATE TABLE jobs (
 id int(11) NOT NULL,
 jobOwnerId int(11) NOT NULL,
 caption varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 description text,
 districtId int(11) NOT NULL,
 address text NOT NULL,
 poster text,
 contactPerson varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 createdAt datetime NOT NULL,
 updatedAt datetime NOT NULL
```

)

here's is the query result shown on console

```
SELECT jobs.id, jobs.jobOwnerId, jobs.caption, jobs.description, jobs.districtId, jobs.address,
jobs.poster, jobs.contactPerson, jobs.createdAt, jobs.userId, owner.id AS owner.id, owner.profilePicture AS owner.profilePicture,
owner->user.id AS owner.user.id, owner->user.name AS owner.user.name, owner->district.id 
AS owner.district.id, owner->district.name AS owner.district.name FROM jobs AS jobs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobOwners AS owner ON jobs.jobOwnerId = owner.id LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS owner->user 
ON owner.userId = owner->user.id LEFT OUTER JOIN districts AS owner->district ON owner.districtId = owner->district.id;
```

there should be no jobs.userId

Comment: what kind of associations does the `user` table have?  in particular, is `user` associated with `jobs`?  does the above `findAll()` succeed if you remove the user include?

Comment: You can see on my model, jobs only have association to owner and districts, i also mention it on my question that i've tried to remove all include but still get the same error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the problem not from jobs model or jobs controller, but it comes from users model, i create association hasMany  jobs and it couses the problem..